# How can I create a smarter .htaccess file that will add a directory?

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my current .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) /directory/ [R=301,L]
```

And "directory" is where my wordpress install is. So this simply redirects people from the root domain to the directory.

What I would like to do is create it so any information added to the url is passed through when the directory is added. SO `http://yoursite.tld/page` becomes `http://yoursite.tld/directory/page/`

I know this is probably a snap for someone with more experience with regular expressions. Unfortunately I haven't been able to track down the info with standard web searches. Appreciate the help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) /directory/$1 [R=301,L]
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule look at "backreferencing"

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. 2 characters... I feel foolish and grateful.